# The algorithm to overlay of two mesh systems

Tags: c#, geometry, computational-geometry

I have two systems of mesh, which are consist of Delaunay Triangulation. One can view this as a Triangulated Irregular Network (TIN).

The algorithm I can think of  for adding or subtracting two TINs ( `t1` and `t2`) can be summarized as follows:

1. Find [the overlay ( or clip)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system#Map_overlay) of two TINs
2. For each point in the overlay, find the `z1` and `z2` resulted from the two TINs.
3. Develop a Delaunay Triangulation for all the points in the overlay, and then use the `z1` and `z2` information above, one can thus create a tetrahedral for each triangle.

The question is, is there any existing C++ or C# library that already implement this ( or a variant of this)?

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution is to perform boolean operations (union, add etc) on the meshes. Boolean operations are fairly well defined on triangular meshes. The best library that implements these is the [GNU Triangulated Surface Library](http://gts.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

Comment: interesting, but it seems that it is no longer in development? I'll spend sometime studying on it and then see how it goes