# Fast boolean operation between two groups of meshes

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, matlab

This is a trimmed down question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584704/the-algorithm-to-overlay-of-two-mesh-systems). Basically I'm just asking about the No. 1 in the question.

Let's say I have two groups of [meshes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh), The definition of the mesh class is as follows ( C# syntax):

```
public class Mesh
{
 public List<Element> elements;
 public List<Point> points;
}

public class Element
{
  public List<int> PointIndex;
}

public class Point
{
  public double X;
  public double Y;
}
```

Is there any efficient way/ implementation to find the resulting of boolean operations ( in my case I would like to find the **polygonal-style intersection**) between two `Mesh`s?

The naive way would be to loop through all the `Element`s inside the `Mesh` object, check against other `Element` in another `Mesh` object, and obtain the results.

But I believe there are more efficient algorithm to do this-- [utilizing plane sweeping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

It would be greater if such algorithm is already implemented elsewhere, either in .Net, C++ or matlab.

Comment: Are you looking for a set-style intersection (that is, all points that exist in both Mesh A and Mesh B) or a polygonal-style intersection (all points that are geometrically within both meshes)?

Comment: @Zac, I'm looking for a polygonal-style intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Just meshes are not enough to do boolean operations on it.

```
class B
{
public:
   virtual bool Inside(Point p) const=0;
};
```

After that additional information, boolean operations are trivial:

```
class Intersect : public B
{
public:
   Intersect(B &b1, B &b2) : b1(b1), b2(b2) { }
   bool Inside(Point p) const { return b1.Inside(p) && b2.Inside(p); }
private:
   B &b1;
   B &b2;
};
```

But getting a mesh out of that structure is considerably more difficult. You're not going to get anything useful out of it. Best solution is something like marching cubes and the meshes you get from that are not going to look any good.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh boolean operations are hard to get right, you're right to try to use some existing code.

One existing C++ library that could suit your needs is CGAL.

You could take a look at the [manual](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.5/doc_html/cgal_manual/Boolean_set_operations_2/Chapter_main.html).

Comment: as explained in the question, I'm looking to do polygon polygon overlay operation in a large scale, so I'm looking for something more efficient than the naive algorithm, which is just intersecting each and every polygon inside the `Mesh` list.

Comment: I did understand that you have multiple polygons. CGAL hopefully supports boolean operations on polygon sets, not only on single polygons, take a look at 'Performing Aggregated Operations' in the manual.

Comment: That's the reason why I came from Unity to Unreal Engine. Month ago I had similar problem and figured it out that without external libraries it will be extremally painful.

Comment: What are some common pitfalls when it comes to implementing mesh Boolean operations?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast and robust implementation of [Boolean operations](https://meshinspector.github.io/MeshLib/html/group__BooleanGroup.html) for triangular meshes in C++ open-source library [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme).

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhJ9Y07MfoE) of MeshInspector application based on MeshLib, where the authors even claim that they can be performed in real-time for moderately complex meshes.

Answer (score -1):

In C++, this can be done much more efficiently if you keep the Mesh's sorted (or sort them before the operations), and use std::set_intersection.  To do this, you'll have to add some sort of ordering relationship to Point.  (The language will automatically generate the ordering operators for the other classes, supposing that in C++, List is a standard container; probably vector or deque).

Comment: first, how do you "sort" the `Mesh`? Second, the Element ( or polygon) intersection is different from the usual `set_intersection`.